# How to find the maximum area when the length is constant

Tags: geometry, analysis

You are given a line segment $AB$ and a random point $M$ in $AB$ 
we consider two halflines $a,b$ from $A,B$  perpendicular to $AB$ which belong to the same halfplane . In $a,b$ we consider $C,D$ such that $CM+DM$ is constant.

Find the positions of $C,D$ such that the area $[AMC]+[BMD]$ is maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let us assume $AM=u, MB=v$ and $AB=1$. We want to find
$$ \max_{\substack{x+y=\ell \\ x\geq u, y\geq v}}u\sqrt{x^2-u^2}+v\sqrt{y^2-v^2}$$
and the function $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2-1}$ is concave over $[1,+\infty)$.
 By Lagrange multipliers the maximum is attained at a point such that

$$ \frac{ux}{\sqrt{x^2-u^2}} = \frac{vy}{\sqrt{y^2-v^2}} $$
or $(x,y)=\lambda(u,v)=\left(\frac{u\ell}{u+v},\frac{v\ell}{u+v}\right).$

It follows that the maximum value of $[AMC]+[BMD]$ is 
$$ \frac{u^2+v^2}{2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\ell}{u+v}\right)^2-1}. $$

The given problem has a nice relation with [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law): I will leave you to find it.

Comment: @Lerigorilla: you were right, I solved a different problem before. Proof now fixed.

Comment: What does λ (u,v)means

Comment: @Lerigorilla: it means $(x,y)=(\lambda u,\lambda v)$, i.e. that $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ are proportional.

Comment: In particular the maximum is attained when the angle bisector of $CMD$ is orthogonal to $AB$, i.e. when the $CM$ ray is "reflected" by the $AB$ side.

Comment: So CMA and DMB are similar

Comment: @Lerigorilla: exactly.